# Array Class to Array of Arrays in Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

In typescript, I need to convert an array class and feed it to other source. Kindly help to achieve the following in elegant way.

```
data : target[] = [{Name : "XXX", Age : "31",DOB : "20-12-1988", Resource: "Java"},
{Name : "YYY", Age : "21",DOB : "20-12-1998", Resource: "Dot Net"},
{Name : "ZZZ", Age : "31",DOB : "1-12-1988", Resource: "SQL"},
{Name : "AAA", Age : "26",DOB : "20-12-1988", Resource: "Angular"},
{Name : "BBB", Age : "28",DOB : "20-12-1988", Resource: "React"},]
```

Expected results after converting

```
[["XXX","31","Java"],["YYY","21","Dot Net"],["ZZZ","31","SQL"],["AAA","26","Angular"],["BBB","28","React"]]
```

Can you suggest me the best way to do it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `.map()` with `Object.values()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```js
let input = [{Name : "XXX", Age : "31",DOB : "20-12-1988", Resource: "Java"},
{Name : "YYY", Age : "21",DOB : "20-12-1998", Resource: "Dot Net"},
{Name : "ZZZ", Age : "31",DOB : "1-12-1988", Resource: "SQL"},
{Name : "AAA", Age : "26",DOB : "20-12-1988", Resource: "Angular"},
{Name : "BBB", Age : "28",DOB : "20-12-1988", Resource: "React"}];

let result = input.map(({Name,Age,Resource}) => [Name,Age,Resource]);
console.log(result);
```